Savitzky golay with missing observations
Has anyone attempted to use savitzky-golay filters in conjunction with interpolation of missing observations? It seems very logical to do so, but I was wondering if there are any good reasons for not doing it since my search has yielded no results.

Could it be that SG are usually implemented as IIR filters (because of computation cost), and handling missing data becomes more cumbersome than what suggested by polynomial fitting?
